# Laravel - Error while running php artisan - with MAMP PRO

Tags: laravel-5, mamp-pro

First steps with Laravel 5 on MacOSX running MAMP PRO stack.

```
php artisan
```

I got the following error:

> [RuntimeException]
>   Error Output: PHP Warning: 
>   require(/Users/../../bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in
>   /Users/../../bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
>   PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required
>   '/Users/../../bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_p
>   ath='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/lib/php') in
>   /Users/../../bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17

It seems to be related with some bootstrap autoload and MAMP php binaries... But this is as far as I can understand this.

Can I have some advices please?

If I run `composer update` instead, I do get the same Fatal Error.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have give a wrong path,re install the laravel.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your answers.
I had some issues with composer assets plugin. I have:

1) Remove the folder related to the composer assets plugin.

2) Reinstalled.

3) go to the root diretory of my laravel project.

4) run `sudo composer install`

Runned `php artisan` and all seems to be working as expected.

Thank you so much for your time.